# How to prevent unknown addresses which are accessed from my wordpress website

Tags: urls, security

I developed a website using wordpress. In the log file (which shows the ip addresses and the pages which have been accessed) I got some unknown addresses which have been accessed from my site although they are not actually exist.
These addresses have been accessed from many parts of the world. Some example addresses are:

xxx/c3e/bfv-fake-gps-without-allow-mock-locations
xxx/c3e/bfv-software-to-monitor-computer-activity-remotely-free 
xxx/rl8/bbx/7-hack-app-that-allow-you-to-view-wifes-or-girlfriends-facebook-secretly.html 
xxx/c3e/bfv-keylogger-for-windows-phone

here xxx represents my actual web address.
Do you have any idea about these address, their purpose and how to prevent these?

Comment: This could be [referrer spam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referrer_spam)

Answer (score 1):

If the requesting IPs are more or less random it's not possible to block them. If they all have a pattern reoccuring you could do that. In your example urls all requests start with the same (not existing) slug (c3e) - you could redirect requests starting with that slug using a htaccess rewrite rule to prevent Wordpress to do stuff that leads to nothing basically.